# In-class initialization of data members. Will the value left after the inheritance?

Tags: c++11

So simple question is, if I have such situation:

```
class FooA{
public:
    int getID(){
        return ID;
    }
private:
    int generateID(){
        //some code that generate unique ID
    }
    int ID = generateID();
};

class FooB : public FooA{

};
```

Will the ID initialized in the FooA goes also to the FooB? So for FooB I can use getID and for example get value from FooA::generateID.

Comment: The short answer is "Yes". The long answer is try it and come back with a post if it does not work.

Comment: Can't try it now, but need answer. If you are sure, then answer it, and I will mark topic as solved.

Comment: Can you post a sample `main`? I'm confused on whether you mean a single instance of FooB accessing its base class, or if you're asking whether multiple instances of FooB will share the same `ID` value.

Comment: Just wasn't sure if FooB object have `ID = generateID()`. I never used before in-class initialization of data member, always I do it in constructor, and classes don't inherit constructors :). So now I know that it's a nice trick to set ID without share generateID method with children classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every instance of both classes will run generateID anew, producing unique value for every instance.
No, ID generated for an instance of parent class won't be same as ID generated for an instance of descendant, because they would have different instances.
Yes, descendant can use or expose parent's methods.

```
class FooA{
    public:
        int getID(){
            return ID;
        }
    private:
        int generateID(){
           static int i = 0;
           return i++;
        }
        int ID = generateID();
    };

    class FooB : public FooA{

    };

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    cout <<  (FooA()).getID() << endl; // 0
    cout <<  (FooA()).getID() << endl; // 1
    cout <<  (FooB()).getID() << endl; // 2
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/5Klf3d